# How to convert db poller xml configurations to java configurations using java dsl in spring integration

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

Trying to do polling the database in spring integration. I have XML code but I want to convert XML config to java DSL.

XML Code:

```
<context:component-scan
    base-package="org.springintegration.polling.dbpoller" />

<int:channel id="fromdb">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>
<int:poller default="true" fixed-rate="5000" />
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/springboot" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="mh" />
</bean>
<int:service-activator input-channel="fromdb"
    ref="jdbcMessageHandler" />
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter
    channel="fromdb" data-source="dataSource" query="SELECT * FROM Items WHERE INVENTORY_STATUS = 0"
    update="UPDATE Items SET INVENTORY_STATUS = 1">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="4000" />
</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

I don't have much knowledge about java DSL. Can someone tell me how to convert it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no JDBC-specific Java DSL factories and builders, but the component behind a `<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>` can be used in the `IntegrationFlow` definition.
See this doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/overview.html#finding-class-names-for-java-and-dsl-configuration

So, a Java class for the `<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>` is mentioned here:

```
<xsd:element name="inbound-channel-adapter">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            Defines a Polling Channel Adapter for the
            'org.springframework.integration.jdbc.JdbcPollingChannelAdapter'
            for polling a database.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
```

The `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter` is a `MessageSource` implementation and therefore can be used in Java DSL with this factory method in the `IntegrationFlows`:

```
/**
 * Populate the provided {@link MessageSource} object to the {@link IntegrationFlowBuilder} chain.
 * The {@link org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow} {@code startMessageSource}.
 * In addition use {@link SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec} to provide options for the underlying
 * {@link org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter} endpoint.
 * @param messageSource the {@link MessageSource} to populate.
 * @param endpointConfigurer the {@link Consumer} to provide more options for the
 * {@link org.springframework.integration.config.SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean}.
 * @return new {@link IntegrationFlowBuilder}.
 * @see MessageSource
 * @see SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec
 */
public static IntegrationFlowBuilder from(MessageSource<?> messageSource,
        @Nullable Consumer<SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec> endpointConfigurer) {
```

The `poller` could be configured using that `endpointConfigurer` callback and via `Pollers` factory.

The `<int:service-activator>` is just `handle()` in Java DSL and there is no reason to specify a channel between your `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter` in the `from()` factory and next `.handle()` in the method chain. It just inserted there naturally in between to let us to avoid boilerplate code for direct channels.

Comment: Let say I defined processMessages() for receiving the rows from DB. How can get the rows from the handler fucntion .handle(processMessages())?

Comment: The `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter` returns those rows from DB to be produced into a channel. So, your `processMessages()` should accept those rows as an argument `List<?>` (or see `rowMapper` option on that `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter` to build some domain-specific POJO from the row). Then you can use your method as `handle(this, "processMessages")`

Comment: Thank you it worked and able to receive rowset in List<Map<String, Object>>. Also, After receiving the rows in the payload, how can I acknowledge the rowset if it is empty?
If i use isEmpty method i.e., if(payload.isEmpty()){} 
then this if statement never execute in this case.

Comment: When no data returned from the DB, the channel adapter doesn’t produce a message. So, if you get list in your service method then it definitely has some data.

Comment: Is there is any way to log/print message in console if the list is empty?